# End of script output before headers (Python, xampp, windows)

Tags: python, xampp

I have setup my xampp server on a windows system, added .py to addhandlers and have the following python script in my htdocs

```
#!G:\Python\python
import MySQLdb
import cgi
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                       user="root",
                       passwd="",
                       db="pro1")
cursor = conn.cursor()

form=cgi.FieldStorage()
uname =form.getvalue('username')
pas =form.getvalue('password')

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Uname` ='"+ uname + "' AND `pass` = '" + pas + "' ;")

if cursor.fetchone() is not None:
    print("Location: http://localhost/project/send.html")
    print()
    print()
else:
    print("Location: http://localhost/project/index1.html")
    print()
    print()

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

after running the file I am getting the following error:
Error message: 
End of script output before headers

i've referred several similar questions and adopted any solutions that seem fitting to my code but nothing works.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I solved it. I didnt have my python interface to mysql set up.